# Postgresql More than onw row returned by a subquery in a insert to script

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to create entries based on the id's of a `SELECT` query, but i cant manage to do this in anyway, tried `UNION ALL` but im not experto on SQL.

this is my current code, the `SELECT` works fine alone, but with `INSERT INTO` it gives me the error "**more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression**"

```
INSERT INTO payment_consent_state (
    id,
    consent_id, 
    status, 
    created_at
)
SELECT uuid_in(overlay(overlay(md5(random()::text || ':' || random()::text) placing '4' from 13) placing to_hex(floor(random()*(11-8+1) + 8)::int)::text from 17)::cstring) as id,
(SELECT consent_id FROM payment_consent_state
    WHERE  created_at < current_timestamp - interval '185 minutes'
    GROUP BY consent_id
    HAVING COUNT(consent_id) = 1)
,
'REJECTED' as status,
now() as data
```

Comment: The inner select `(SELECT consent_id FROM payment_consent_state
    WHERE  created_at < current_timestamp - interval '185 minutes'
    GROUP BY consent_id
    HAVING COUNT(consent_id) = 1)` is likely returning more than one row. Try changing `SELECT consent_id` to `SELECT max(consent_id)` to see if that at makes it execute. If so, figure out *which* `consent_id` you want from the many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this helpful :

```
INSERT INTO payment_consent_state (
    id,
    consent_id, 
    status, 
    created_at
)
SELECT uuid_in(overlay(overlay(md5(random()::text || ':' || random()::text) placing '4' from 13) placing to_hex(floor(random()*(11-8+1) + 8)::int)::text from 17)::cstring) as id,
consent_id,
'REJECTED' as status,
now() as data
FROM payment_consent_state
WHERE  created_at < current_timestamp - interval '185 minutes'
GROUP BY consent_id
HAVING COUNT(consent_id) = 1)
```

This considered as multi rows itself

```
(SELECT consent_id FROM payment_consent_state
    WHERE  created_at < current_timestamp - interval '185 minutes'
    GROUP BY consent_id
    HAVING COUNT(consent_id) = 1)
```